# Google Sheets ui access on mobile?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can you use SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from Android / Mobile version of Google Sheets?

If not how can I create a button or some dialog box from within the Android version of Google Sheets?

Comment: This isn't possible on mobile, but see this answer for a (clunky) workaround: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87346/add-a-script-trigger-to-google-sheet-that-will-work-in-android-mobile-app

Comment: That solution is for creating a dropdown menu, not a dialog box, as was asked by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew Roberts said, it is not possible in mobile. However, I found this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/mobile/) that shows the things that you can do in Android by using Apps Script.

It uses [Apps Script Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/) to directly call functions in Apps Script projects. This allows Android add-ons to retrieve and manipulate data from a Google Doc or Sheet using standard Apps Script techniques.

Just take note the things that you can't do with this.

- Change features in Google Apps
- Affect the Docs or Sheets editor apps
- Create and adjust triggers

For more information, check this [Google Docs Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/wrxud5AGs7Q).

Comment: That first link is now dead.