# why is my trigger status "Paused" when triggered from mobile

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mobile, dialog, alert

I implemented a button click workaround feature using data validation in Google Sheets and whenever the trigger gets executed from mobile, it's in "Paused" status. I am displaying dialog box when this trigger gets executed, which, works perfectly fine when executed from the browser.

[image]

**Code snippet:**

```
function onSheetEdit(e) {
    ...
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ...
   
    var result = ui.alert(
      'Confirmation',
      Text,
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
      ...
      // Executed on OK
      ui.showModelessDialog(
          HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setHeight(20),
          'Redirecting'
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [UI dialog isn't shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50902054/3751868) using the mobile app, so the script just stays paused waiting for the dialog to be closed. A workaround would be to [show the message as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57480181/google-apps-script-toast-messages-dont-appear-for-anonymous-editors/57486785#57486785).

Related questions:

[Google Sheets ui access on mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40030031/google-sheets-ui-access-on-mobile)

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87346/add-a-script-trigger-to-google-sheet-that-will-work-in-android-mobile-app